# Adsense Google MAP API not showing up the MAP

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am following this link to create Adsense on GMAP https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/ads-adunit

But when i implemented it on my website only ads and some part of MAP only highlighted, I also tried to debug the view from the firebug tool but not found any hidden property or error. The same code i have implemented.

[pastebin.com/AbEEExSa](http://pastebin.com/AbEEExSa)

[image: GMAP]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it shows grey color in the `map-canvas`, it seems to be a refresh problem.  This can be solved by triggering the **`resize`** of the Google maps.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

Try adding this line after the completion of `adunit` API(success callback of this API).

> **FYI:**
>   `resize` : Developers should trigger this event on the map when the
>   div changes size: `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')`.

### Updates:

I tried using the code that you have pasted in codebin, removing the php and parts that you have commented.  It is [**working**](http://jsfiddle.net/ngcxS/1/).  I'm not sure what your php code does.  So try debugging like in the fiddle.

Comment: i have implemented it just before the initialize function closed but remain the same.

Comment: @jogesh_pi Before means at the end of the initialize method right?

Comment: even i tried to display only map( commented the adunit API ), but nothing happen.

Comment: @jogesh_pi I tried the same thing by commenting the adUnit API and it is working for me http://jsfiddle.net/ngcxS/

Comment: yes, it is not working on my local host, beside that i also tried on jsfiddle and its working other then my localhost :(

Comment: @jogesh_pi seems strange, I guess this might be a simple issue which is not in your code.  can you share your HTML, cs?

Comment: I tried like the fiddle but still not working, i remove all the commented part and php part as well, i also check in firebug console but not getting any error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41700/discussion-between-praveen-jeganathan-and-jogesh-pi)